# Ubuntu 13.04 not USB tethering through Android

Tags: 13.04, android, tethering

Just upgraded to 13.04. Now my internet doesn't work anymore through my Galaxy Note 2. It used to work perfectly in 12.10 without a hitch. The phone's got Android 4.1

There's no error message. The phone connects, Ubuntu pops up with a message that it found a new network, and shows that this is connected. But nothing wants to link on the internet, not Firefox, not Thunderbird, not even the Software Centre.

Comment: I'm using a Galaxy Nexus with Cyanogenmod (Android 4.3) and using Ubuntu 13.04. After plugin in my phone to my computer, I select USB tethering as an option on my phone, immediately I see a new Ethernet connection created on my Network Manager. I simply select that network and I'm connected to my phone. I don't see any pop-up messages telling about a new network. Actually, if I wouldn't have check the network manager, I would have thought that it didn't work and nothing happened.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, and I could not figure it out. The way I solved it was to unplug my phone go to "Edit Connections" and delete my phones connection profile, then plug the phone back in, a new connection is created automatically.